# Issue with maps, for loops and list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
kn = input().split(" ")
n = int(kn[0])
k = int(kn[1])
niz = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
newlis = []   
def rad(o):   
    return sum(niz[num:(num+k+o)])/(k+o)   
def posao(k):   
    return max(list(map(rad, range(0, n-k))))
for num in range(len(niz[0:(n-k+1)])):
    newlis.append(max(list(map(rad, range(0, n-num))))) 
#newlis = [max(list(map(rad, range(0, n-num)))) for num in range(len(niz[0:(n-k+1)]))]
print(max(newlis))
```

So I've got this working with a for loop and now I want to use the commented out list comprehension (or even `map()`) to make it faster. Problem is, it keeps returning that `num is not defined` when I use either. I'm completely aware the code is very messy and unclean, but if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong with this, I'd appreciate it. I'm only a beginner with python.

Comment: Prime example of why you should use descriptive variables...

Comment: Can you describe, in words, what you want this to do?

Comment: Also, ```map``` is typically not very fast, especially when you convert it to a list

Comment: It's a solution to task "PROSJEK" here: http://www.hsin.hr/coci/contest7_tasks.pdf. I've got it working except for being too slow for a too large list due to the for loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def rad(o):   
    return sum(niz[num:(num+k+o)])/(k+o)  // I guess the problem should 
   // be here... as ^ num is not defined in this function and neither it is a global variable
```

Try passing num as argument

```
def rad(o,num):   
    return sum(niz[num:(num+k+o)])/(k+o)
newlis = [max([rad(x, num) for x in range(0, n-num)]) for num in range(len(niz[0:(n-k+1)]))]
```

Comment: I see it now... got any ideas as to getting it to work? I've thought about converting the first map to a list comprehension but I really want to squeeze every bit of speed out of this.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm not sure how I never thought of that. I'm only 4 months into python so there's a bunch of stuff I don't yet know.

Comment: @BornaŠimić Does it work as needed...? If this solves your problem accept the answer :p